# Why do `as` methods remove vector names, and is there a way around it?

Tags: r, type-conversion

Basically, I'm trying to keep a vector named `dates` of special `Date`s that come up a lot in my analysis, say New Year's 2016 and July 4 2015. I want to be able to extract from this by name instead of index for robustness, e.g., `dates["nyd"]` to get New Year's and `dates["ind"]` to get July 4.

I thought this would be simple:

```
dates <- as.Date(c(ind = "2015-07-04", nyd = "2016-01-01"))
```

But `as.Date` has stripped the names:

```
dates
# [1] "2015-07-04" "2016-01-01"
```

It's not like `Date` vectors can't be named (which would be strange, given they're basically specifically-interpreted `integer`s):

```
setNames(dates, c("ind", "nyd"))
#          ind          nyd 
# "2015-07-04" "2016-01-01"
```

And unfortunately there's no way to declare a `Date` vector directly (as far as I know?), especially without knowing the underlying integer values of the dates.

Exploring this, it seems this is standard practice for the `as*` class of functions:

```
as.integer(c(a = "123", b = "436"))
# [1] 123 436

as(c(a = 1, b = 2), "character")
# [1] "1" "2"
```

Is there a reason why this is the case? The loss of names isn't mentioned in `?as` or any of the other help pages I've seen.

More generally, is there a way (using something other than `as*`) to ensure the names of an object are not lost in a conversion?

Of course one approach is to write custom functions like `as.Date.named` or create a custom class `as.named` with associated methods, but it would be surprising to me if there wasn't something like this already in place, as it seems like this should be a pretty common operation.

In case it matters, I'm on 3.2.2.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bug, just something that could be potentially added in as a feature request in the future. Assuming that we're not both overlooking something!

Comment: `as.integer/character/etc` are documented to ignore "attributes". On the other hand, `as.Date(c(a = as.POSIXlt(Sys.time())))` VS `as.Date(c(a = as.POSIXct(Sys.time())))`, as well as, `as(c(a = 1, b = 2), "integer")` VS `as(c(a = 1, b = 2), "character")` seem a bit surprising.

Comment: @alexis_laz hmm it seems you're right, `?as.vector` and `?as.double` both mention stripping attributes. Thanks for the heads up. As to the difference between `as.POSIXlt` and `as.POSIXct`, simply look at `as.Date.POSIXlt` as compares to `as.Date.POSIXct`. The former goes to the `Internal` function `POSIXlt2Date` while the latter at core uses `unclass`, which doesn't strip the name.

Comment: @alexis_laz as to the latter, i'm guessing we hit a `return` statement of the original object before any conversion is done (hence no lost attributes)

Comment: @MichaelChirico Indeed `POSIXlt2Date` ignores "names" inside its code, but I guess we could expect that the `POSIXlt` and `POSIXct` methods of `as.Date` to behave similarly; more surprisingly see `as.Date(c(a = as.POSIXct(Sys.time())), tz = "UTC")` VS `as.Date(c(a = as.POSIXct(Sys.time())), tz = "GMT")`. The ... `as`es... both convert (unless I misunderstood your second comment) because `c(a = 1, b = 2)` is "numeric"; `as(, "character")` ends up calling `as.character` which is why the "names" are lost but I, still, think that we could expect the same behavior..?

Comment: @alexis_laz  Don't see the point of `as.POSIXct(Sys.time())`. `Sys.time()` is already in `"POSIXct" "POSIXt"` class.

Comment: @Pascal I assume that's just for emphasis (?) -- I for one certainly couldn't recall the class of `Sys.time()` by sight

Comment: @MichaelChirico  I just see a redundancy, but, well, OK.

Comment: @Pascal : In my second comment, it is, indeed, not needed; I initially used it to direct in the difference between `as.Date.POSIXct` and `as.Date.POSIXlt`.

Comment: I don't think `as.Date.POSIXlt` should remove the names. All `as.Date` methods should behave the same in this regard. You should report this (might be worth a carefully worded e-mail to r-devel).

Comment: @Roland if they should all behave the same, then isn't `as.Date.POSIXct` the "odd man out"? it's the only conversion method I've seen that _keeps_ names

Comment: @MichaelChirico Well, `as.Date.character` calls `as.Date.POSIXlt` internally. `as.Date.numeric` preserves the names.

Comment: `as.matrix` also keeps the names, though they become row names.  A related question might be why do the type conversion functions collapse arrays into vectors (e.g. `as.character(matrix(1:4, 2, 2))`).

Comment: If the goal is to access the dates by `names` would it be better if you convert your vectors to `list` ?                                                                                 `x <- list(ind = "2015-07-04", nyd = "2016-01-01")`
`y <- lapply(x, as.Date)`
`sapply(y,class)`
`y["ind"]`

Answer (score 9):

Indeed there is a discrepancy in the different `as.Date` methods and here is why (or rather "how"):

First, your example:

```
> as.Date(c(ind = "2015-07-04", nyd = "2016-01-01"))
[1] "2015-07-04" "2016-01-01"
```

Here we use method `as.Date.character`:

```
> as.Date.character
function (x, format = "", ...) 
{
    charToDate <- function(x) {
        xx <- x[1L]
        if (is.na(xx)) {
            j <- 1L
            while (is.na(xx) && (j <- j + 1L) <= length(x)) xx <- x[j]
            if (is.na(xx)) 
                f <- "%Y-%m-%d"
        }
        if (is.na(xx) || !is.na(strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d", 
            tz = "GMT")) || !is.na(strptime(xx, f <- "%Y/%m/%d", 
            tz = "GMT"))) 
            return(strptime(x, f))
        stop("character string is not in a standard unambiguous format")
    }
    res <- if (missing(format)) 
        charToDate(x)
    else strptime(x, format, tz = "GMT")
    as.Date(res)
}
<bytecode: 0x19d3dff8>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

Whether the format is given or not, your vector is passed to `strptime` which converts it to class POSIXlt, and then it is passed to `as.Date` again but this time with method `as.Date.POSIXlt` which is:

```
> as.Date.POSIXlt
function (x, ...) 
.Internal(POSIXlt2Date(x))
<bytecode: 0x19d2df50>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

meaning that ultimately the function used to convert to class Date is the C function called by `POSIXlt2Date` (a quick look at file `names.c` show that the function is `do_POSIXlt2D` from file [`datetime.c`](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/main/datetime.c#L1240)). For reference, here it is:

```c
SEXP attribute_hidden do_POSIXlt2D(SEXP call, SEXP op, SEXP args, SEXP env)
{
    SEXP x, ans, klass;
    R_xlen_t n = 0, nlen[9];
    stm tm;

    checkArity(op, args);
    PROTECT(x = duplicate(CAR(args)));
    if(!isVectorList(x) || LENGTH(x) < 9)
    error(_("invalid '%s' argument"), "x");

    for(int i = 3; i < 6; i++)
    if((nlen[i] = XLENGTH(VECTOR_ELT(x, i))) > n) n = nlen[i];
    if((nlen[8] = XLENGTH(VECTOR_ELT(x, 8))) > n) n = nlen[8];
    if(n > 0) {
    for(int i = 3; i < 6; i++)
        if(nlen[i] == 0)
        error(_("zero-length component in non-empty \"POSIXlt\" structure"));
    if(nlen[8] == 0)
        error(_("zero-length component in non-empty \"POSIXlt\" structure"));
    }
    /* coerce relevant fields to integer */
    for(int i = 3; i < 6; i++)
    SET_VECTOR_ELT(x, i, coerceVector(VECTOR_ELT(x, i), INTSXP));

    PROTECT(ans = allocVector(REALSXP, n));
    for(R_xlen_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    tm.tm_sec = tm.tm_min = tm.tm_hour = 0;
    tm.tm_mday  = INTEGER(VECTOR_ELT(x, 3))[i%nlen[3]];
    tm.tm_mon   = INTEGER(VECTOR_ELT(x, 4))[i%nlen[4]];
    tm.tm_year  = INTEGER(VECTOR_ELT(x, 5))[i%nlen[5]];
    /* mktime ignores tm.tm_wday and tm.tm_yday */
    tm.tm_isdst = 0;
    if(tm.tm_mday == NA_INTEGER || tm.tm_mon == NA_INTEGER ||
       tm.tm_year == NA_INTEGER || validate_tm(&tm) < 0)
        REAL(ans)[i] = NA_REAL;
    else {
        /* -1 must be error as seconds were zeroed */
        double tmp = mktime00(&tm);
        REAL(ans)[i] = (tmp == -1) ? NA_REAL : tmp/86400;
    }
    }

    PROTECT(klass = mkString("Date"));
    classgets(ans, klass);
    UNPROTECT(3);
    return ans;
}
```

Unfortunately my understanding of C is too limited to know why the attributes are lost here. My guess would be that it happens either during the `coerceVector` operation or when each element of the POSIXlt list is individually coerced to integers (if that's what happens lines 1268-70).

But let's have a look at the other `as.Date` method, starting with the main offender, `as.Date.POSIXct`:

```r
> as.Date.POSIXct
function (x, tz = "UTC", ...) 
{
    if (tz == "UTC") {
        z <- floor(unclass(x)/86400)
        attr(z, "tzone") <- NULL
        structure(z, class = "Date")
    }
    else as.Date(as.POSIXlt(x, tz = tz))
}
<bytecode: 0x19c268bc>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

With this one, if no timezone is given, or if the timezone is "UTC", the function just manipulate the `POSIXct` lists to extract the data that can be resolved to a Date object, thus not losing the attributes, but **if any other timezones is given, it is then converted to a `POSIXlt` object and therefore passed further to the same `POSIXlt2Date` internal**, which eventually lose its attributes! And indeed:

```
> as.Date(c(a = as.POSIXct("2016-01-01")), tz="UTC")
           a 
"2015-12-31" 

> as.Date(c(a = as.POSIXct("2016-01-01")), tz="CET")
[1] "2016-01-01"
```

And finally, as @Roland mentioned, `as.Date.numeric` does keep the attributes:

```
> as.Date.numeric
function (x, origin, ...) 
{
    if (missing(origin)) 
        stop("'origin' must be supplied")
    as.Date(origin, ...) + x
}
<bytecode: 0x568943d4>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

`origin` is converted to Date via `as.Date.character` and then the vector of numeric is added, thus keeping the attributes because of this:

```
> c(a=1) + 2
a 
3
```

So naturally:

```
> c(a=16814) + as.Date("1970-01-01")
           a 
"2016-01-14"
```

Until this discrepancy is taken care of, the only solutions you have to keep your attributes, I think,  are either to first convert to POSIXct (but beware of timezone issues) or to numeric, or to copy the attributes of your original vector:

```
> before <- c(ind = "2015-07-04", nyd = "2016-01-01")
> after <- as.Date(before)
> names(after) <- names(before)
> after
         ind          nyd 
"2015-07-04" "2016-01-01"
```

Comment: The "names" of a "POSIXlt" object are set on its "year" component (see `names<-.POSIXlt`). When a "POSIXlt" is passed to `POSIXlt2Date` there is no explicit get/set of the "names" attribute of the "year" component. `coerceVector` doesn't seem to lose "names" (its R equivalents `as.sth` explicitly set "attributes" to `NULL`), so, I guess, "names" is just ignored? Also, it might be worth to note that `as.POSIXct.POSIXlt` does get the "names" of the "year" component of a "POSIXlt" object to set it to its return value in contrast to `as.Date.POSIXlt` which ignores it (both in C and R code).

Comment: thanks for the thorough answer! seems like writing a general `as.named` method may be worthwhile. The remaining issue is _why_ this is the case -- just "efficiency"?

Comment: @MichaelChirico It might just be an oversight. Report it.

Comment: @Roland that the docs (`?as.vector` and `?as.double`, perhaps more) both mention the loss of names suggests it may not be an oversight. Anyway I have reported it.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a full answer to the question, but as a way round the problem, no-one has mentioned the `mode` function.

```
vec <- c(a = "1", b = "2")
mode(vec) <- "integer"
vec
# returns:
# a b 
# 1 2
```

I'm not sure how you'd apply this to dates though:

```
vec <- c(a = "2010-01-01")
mode(vec) <- "POSIXlt"
```

gives something, but it doesn't seem quite right.

---

You could also use

```
sapply(vec, as.whatever)
```

which will preserve names.  However, I think this will be slower as you lose the advantage of a vectorised function.

---

Thirdly, there is:

```
structure(as.whatever(vec), names = names(vec))
```

Comment: Because with `as` methods you are changing the type of object (e.g. character to numeric).  `mode` allows you to do that without losing the names and therefore constitutes a "way round it", which was asked for in the question.  In short, it gives the desired result, although admittedly the given example with dates will require a bit more work.

Comment: This is interesting, because in theory `mode<-` being a wrapper around `as` methods that save the attributes of the object first and then give them back to the newly converted object, it should work perfectly. But in this case, somehow, the operation `attributes(new_Date_vector) <- attributes(old_character_vector)` coerces the new Date vector into an integer vector! (Same thing happens with `sapply`).

Comment: I must admit that I am unfamiliar with the POSIX system in R.  For myself I use a function which converts day, month and year into an integer (days since 30/12/1899) which is consistent with (but better than) MS Excel.  However, these solutions are general approaches to the problem of type conversion retaining names.

Comment: Just noticed that `grep` does exactly the `structure(as.character(x), names = names(x))` approach